# Berry–Esseen bound for operator norm of matrix averages

Tags: pr.probability, asymptotics, random-matrices

Is there a Berry–Esseen bound for operator norm of an average of independent random matrices?

Suppose $A_1, \dotsc, A_n$ are independent matrices with $\mathbb{E}[A_i] = I$ (the identity matrix). Is there a Berry–Esseen bound for properly normalized $\lVert\overline{A} - I\rVert_\text{op}$?

Comment: Given how underdeveloped the field of Matrix Chernoff like bounds is, a Berry Esseen type result seems too strong to currently exist, unfortunately. What do you need to bound? Maybe a simpler type of bound will do.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this paper on Berry–Esseen inequalities for random vectors, maybe it will be useful:

[Bentkus - On the dependence of the Berry–Esseen bound
on dimension](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.529.5146).